# Algorihtm / asymptotic performance of setTimeout and clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o, settimeout

What is the algorithm for the implementation of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` in common browsers (Chrome, FF, IE)?

The algorithm that first comes to mind is that timeouts could be maintained on a min heap, sorted by the time to run. The timeouts are removed from the heap soonest first.

```
     1
    / \
   2   7
  / \
 5  5

(where numbers are the UTC time, or something)
```

That would make the asympotic performance

```
setTimeout   - O(log n)
clearTimeout - O(n)
```

Is there such difference between the performance of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`, or is a different algorithm used? (For example, using a heap, but marking timeouts with a "disabled" flag instead of immeadiately finding and removing them from the heap.)

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are both stacked, and run after the minimum interval, when all other blocking activity is cleared. Whatever the theoretical implications of your `asymptotic performance`, in reality, performance is governed by all the other things a browser is expected to do.

Comment: @MikeW, you are correct in that this is unlikely to matter in most (essentially all) cases.